# How to use random_password multiple times in terraform script

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to use random_password multiple times in terraform script. for example:

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 16
  special = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}
resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  instance_class = "db.t3.micro"
  allocated_storage = 64
  engine = "mysql"
  username = "someone"
  password = random_password.password.result
}
```

this will work for one time. what if I need to create

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 16
  special = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}
resource "aws_db_instance" "example1" {
  instance_class = "db.t3.micro"
  allocated_storage = 64
  engine = "mysql"
  username = "someone"
  password = random_password.password.result
}
resource "aws_db_instance" "example2" {
  instance_class = "db.t2.small"
  allocated_storage = 64
  engine = "mysql"
  username = "anyone"
  password = random_password.password.result
}
```

Now I need to create 2 random password. Can I use count in random password?

Answer (score 4):

You can use count or for_each loops.

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  count = 2
  length = 16
  special = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  for_each = random_password.password
  instance_class = "db.t3.micro"
  allocated_storage = 64
  engine = "mysql"
  username = "someone"
  password = each.value.result
}
```

This will result in-
`random_password.password[0].result` and `random_password.password[1].result` for your result values (`random_password.password` without an index is treated like any other map in terraform when for_each or count is used for recursion). I set the count to 2 in the example, but this can be any int.
and
`aws_db_instance.example[0]` and `aws_db_instance.example[1]`, created by the `for_each` loop according to the number of `random_password.password` objects. Within the loop, you reference the resource as `each.value` (therefore, `each.value.result` would be equiv to `random_password.password.result`)

More on `for_each` [here](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/)

EDIT: Important note...this is just for an example of how count/for_each works. It would be really awkward to base your number of instances off the number of passwords you have created (think about it...). You'll want to take a bigger picture view and consider how you actually want to scale your project, then base your count/for_each logic on THAT.

EDIT2 (because I don't have enough karma to comment): There's no reason that output shouldn't work. What version of tf are you using?).

Also, to get a list of the results you could do:

```
output "passwords" {
  value = random_password.password[*].result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I can't use for_each because username and instance_class will be different for every aws_db_instance. I basically eager to know how will I use the random password in different blocks.

Comment: Even this is not working. how can I output the generated password 
output "password0" {
value = "${random_password.password[0].result}"
}

Answer (score 3):

If password requirements are the same for every password you're generating (likely your case), use `count`:

```
resource "random_password" "passwords" {
  count = 2
  length = 16
  special = true
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "db_instance_1" {
  ...
  password = random_password.passwords[0].result
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "db_instance_2" {
  ...
  password = random_password.passwords[1].result
}

output "db_instance_1_password" {
  value = random_password.passwords[0].result
}

output "db_instance_2_password" {
  value = random_password.passwords[1].result
}
```

If password requirements are different, define multiple `random_password` resources:

```
resource "random_password" "password_1" {
  length = 16
  special = true
}

resource "random_password" "password_2" {
  length = 16
  special = false
  min_upper = 1
  min_lower = 1
  min_numeric = 1
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "db_instance_1" {
  ...
  password = random_password.password_1.result
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "db_instance_2" {
  ...
  password = random_password.password_2.result
}

output "db_instance_1_password" {
  value = random_password.password_1.result
}

output "db_instance_2_password" {
  value = random_password.password_2.result
}
```

In both cases, consider setting [`sensitive = true`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html#sensitive-suppressing-values-in-cli-output) in the outputs to hide raw passwords from Terraform command output.

Comment: I might be missing something but would you be unable to rotate a single password using this approach?